# Why do my Achievements constantly reset?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, achievements

My Achievements frequently 'forget' that I've accomplished any of them and reset as if I've never played before. Why does this happen, and is there some kind of fix for it?

Comment: I had this happen once, when I purchased a new machine.  I only play vanilla with no mods.  Never had an update affect achievements.

Comment: I even thought it's a feature - each game gets a new set of achievements. :) [as strange as the idea seemed.]

Comment: As long as they are client-side and not saved online, they are utterly pointless anyway.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm afraid it's just a [bug](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Achievements#Bugs):

> Statistics and achievements sometimes reset for no reason at all.

Achievements also reset when you update the game, install mods, uninstall mods, etc.

Comment: any time the jar is changed really

Answer (score 0):

there is one way i found that can be use to get your stats from the previous session...

this works effectively if you start this from the point you create a new world

step 1> start playing your world in 'minecraft'

step 2> as soon as you enter, press pause and quit (Don't quit the game entirely, just get back to the main menu.)

step 3> come out of the game and open the folder ..\.minecraft\saves\**world name**\stats

setp 4> find the file that was most recently created ex:*filename-some random values*.json (you can confirm this by checking the modified time of the file)

step 5> now find the file that was created when you played the previous session (If you follow this technique from the start, there would only be two files in the folder making it easier to find out which one was created during the current session and the previous session)

step 6> open the previous session file in notepad and copy all its contents

step 7> open the current session file in notepad and overwrite any information present

step 8> save the current session file and delete the previous session file

step 9> get back to your game and enjoy your world

*Hopefully this will help until a fix comes out for this problem*

Answer (score 0):

Replace your 1.7.10 launcher (delete the contents of minecraft launcher folder) with the 1.6.4 launcher. If you have a copy of that saved somewhere on your PC, copy the contents of the Minecraft launcher folder of 1.6.4 and paste it in 1.7.10 (choose your profile and then play), I had the problem but I did this and now it's okay.